# Getting MonoAndroid 7.0

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, nuget-package

I am unable to install Xamarin.Firebase.Database -Pre
Getting the following error

```
    Install failed. Rolling back...
    Package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Database.42.1001.0' does not exist in project                    'AndroidMessaging'
   Package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Database.42.1001.0' does not exist in folder  'c:\users\zanubkhan\documents\visual studio  2015\Projects\AndroidMessaging\packages'
      Install-Package : Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Database  42.1001.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
  targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
  framework. For more information, contact the package author.
  At line:1 char:1
 + Install-Package Xamarin.Firebase.Database -Pre
      + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I also tried to 
      Install-Package Xamarin.Firebase.Database 
it also didn't work.
I checked in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Database/
where they say this package need MonoAndroid 7.0. Since I am new in this field and tried a lot to get MonoAndroid 7.0 but couldn't get useful information. 
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You need to set your `Compile With` version to Android API 7.0 or above. It is currently set to Android API 6.0

Comment: Hi John,  thank you so much for your answer. But unfortunately I cannot see api greater than 6 in compile with frameworks options.

Comment: Then you need to go to your Android SDK and install Android API 7.0!

Comment: Thank you so much...........Finally, I solved the problem using the information given by you......I really appreciate your help, Once again, Thanks a lot :)